# Java Spring: How is the return value of @Async method handled?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, completable-future

Say I have a method

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class AppController {

    @Async
    @PostMapping(value="/")
    public CompletableFuture<> doSomething(@RequestBody ..., HTTPServletResponse response){
         //something; 
     return completableResult;
    }
}
```

I understand that the method will return immediately and release the container thread.

But how is the value returned (after some time) handled?

Is there a listener?

And doesn't that block one of the container threads?

Isn't there something like future.get() executed internally ?

Comment: You have to assign the value returned by `doSomething` which will be a `future`... Then you will have to retrieve it from the `future` yourself... This could be in use if you want to do several async calls to `doSomething` and then collect the returns and use them once all of them are ready.

Comment: what @dbl meant is that there is usually a method called `get()` associated with a future.
So in another service you might call `serviceWithFuture.doSomething(...).get()` to retrieve the actual result once it is there.

Comment: Sorry, but I meant the function doSomething to be a REST endpoint. That function will be called by the Spring dispatcher servlet.  I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method  `doSomething.isDone()` to check if future is ready. You can implement if statement to chech if isDone return true(and call `.get()` method to retrieve what future have). If it returns false it will mean you need to wait for future.

EDIT:
after post was edit my answer is not so connected anymore but I would do that in similar way as I describe.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but for others looking this could be helpful.

First of all:

1. I see you are using both Async and CompletableFuture in the same function.They are used to do the same thing i.e. handling Asynchronous requests.
2. Both of them are capable of doing the same thing independently.
3. **isDone** is not something I would recommend because you have to wait your unknown amount of time to return your values.I feel it's better for the consumer ( frontend ,browser or whoever made the request ) to wait for the response.

**Using @async**

In this we create a **CompletableFuture** object and returns it from the async method . Consumer (Browser or your GET request from frontend ) will wait on this object to complete. After we have done our asynchronous task, which is running on a different thread we complete the **cp** object with the desired value of the CompletableFuture, in our case string. SpringBoot converts your CompletableFuture object to relevant Type of the value.

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> doSomeThing() throws InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<String> cp = new CompletableFuture<String>();
    int i = 5; 
    while(i-- >= 0){
        System.out.println("Doing something ");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } 

    if(i < 0){
        cp.complete("Done doing something ");
    }
    return cp;
}
```

**Using CompletableFuture**

CompletableFuture API has methods ,**runAsync** and **supplyAsync**

1. **runAsync** : methods takes a **Runnable** lambda function.This method is used to compute async task on a different thread without returning anything.
2. **supplyAsync**: method takes a **Supplier** type lambda function and returns a CompletableFuture.

We can use this **supplyAsync** method to return a completablefuture and also run the task in different thread without using the @Async annotation.

```
public CompletableFuture<String> doSomeThing() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> {
        int i =3;
        while(i-- >= 0){
            System.out.println("Doing something ");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "Done doing something";
    });
}
```

Hope this makes things clearer about CompletableFuture. Happy Coding